# Single word for referring to how people relate to sbd/some entity who after shuning their duty do comply, thus making the people tremendously happy

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, synonyms

I need to know if there is a word suitable to describe a state of mind brought about by the following situation: some staff/people  paid/elicited to provide  some service,  knowingly and deliberately do not do so, the reason being that they are given  to some unpardonnable behaviour such as indulging in slackery, turning to delinquency, bribery, nepotism, blind supporting of a negative ideology etc., but,  whatevever the  circumstance motivating them, say peer pressure, bad media coverage, managing a favourable coming poll, etc, they do  all of a sudden carry out their duties. Then, if on the grounds of the reversal of the situation, those people supposed to profit from the service  get euphoric and keep singing out the eulogy of those that have redeemed themselves, while remaining perfectly oblivious of the fact that  those latter, in having fulfilled their duty did nothing but what was normally expected of them, what word might describe how the people using the service now relate to them?

For instance, say a driver has for duty to drive passengers somewhere within certain time limits  and to make the trip confortable to them, and that, instead, for the beginning of the trip he drives very slowly, frequently turns down the engine, drives unattentively, presses hard on the breakes frequently for no reason, and that after this abnormal behaviour he  resumes correct driving; however the passengers remain very happy and [for some reason] praise the driver, for  example because of a respite after so much bad driving; another reason could be a revelation to them that what presages nothing good can be in fact be followed by a return to a normal unfolding of events.

Can any one suggest me a word that expresses that state of mind?

For instance, I am thinking of using that word in a sentence like this one:

- "Those people are given to ----.".

Comment: The use of *suffering from* doesn't match the description of *euphoria* that's described. In fact, it's a contradiction. Do you want something that describes the behaviour that generates the *positive* reaction, or something that describes the person's normal disappointing performance?

Comment: @Jason yes disappointing performance.

Comment: I'm confused, then, by the references to people being happy when the job is done. Why is that important to the question?

Comment: @Jason edited thw question if it gets a bit lucid.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's now more confusing to me than ever. Rather than remove the references to people suddenly being happy, and focusing on the "disappointing performance," you've now added *more* text about people suddenly being happy. So, I still have no idea which particular aspect of these scenarios you're concerned with.

Comment: I think you want *prodigal*, or something related to it. If you’re not already familiar with it, look up *the parable of the prodigal son*, from the Old Testament.

Comment: @DanBron *New* Testament.

Comment: @Lawrence Ah yes, you’re right.

Comment: @Dan Bron Infact i am trying refer government of country rather than a son or so...

Comment: @SIslam so call it the *prodigal government* - prodigal is a generic adjective, not confined in anyway to family or sons. Or go for a little lighthearted pun, like *Celebrating the return of the prodigal State* or something else cutesy.

Comment: @Dan Bron I see money is related to `prodigal` but I need duty. https://www.dictionary.com/browse/prodigal

Answer (score 0):

There is a word fit to express this idea; let's recapitulate what it is: the reaction is found to be one of  indulgence and then it is found to be excessive, inordinate. You might say that the people are given to **overindulgence**.

Answer (score 0):

[Kill the fatted calf](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/kill+the+fatted+calf)?

You could use it figuratively.